# remove /n python from calling a .txt file

Tags: python

here is my code see the picture

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t8EvX.png)

but puzzle01.txt has
[' 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n', ' 0 9 0 7 0 0 8 0 0\n', ' 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 7 0\n', ' 6 0 1 0 0 0 9 8 0\n', ' 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0\n', ' 0 0 9 0 0 0 7 0 1\n', ' 0 0 0 0 0 8 1 9 0\n', ' 0 4 0 5 0 1 0 0 8\n', ' 0 7 0 3 0 6 0 4 0']

need to remove the /n but confused about where to add it each strip I have tried doesn't seem to work, can you help me?

Comment: SO strongly encourages placing the code as text in the question rather than a link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've run into this issue today I used a strip() to remove \n :

```py
test =  [' 5 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0\n', ' 0 9 0 7 0 0 8 0 0\n', ' 0 0 0 0 3 0 0 7 0\n', ' 6 0 1 0 0 0 9 8 0\n', ' 0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 0\n', ' 0 0 9 0 0 0 7 0 1\n', ' 0 0 0 0 0 8 1 9 0\n', ' 0 4 0 5 0 1 0 0 8\n', ' 0 7 0 3 0 6 0 4 0']
newtest = []
for i in test:
    i = i.strip()
    newtest.append(i)
print(newtest)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for line in puzzle:
    board.append(int(line.strip()))
```